# Cannot successfully parse Django DateField in form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have:  `date_due = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)`

and a related model form for the class in which the above occurs.  All other values validate fine in the model form, but when I put in a date in the format August 25, 2017, I receive an error message:  "Enter valid date".  In settings.py I have set `USE_L10N = True` (and also set `USE_L18N = False` to ensure that only the USE_L10N setting is being observed).

In [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) it says:

> A list of formats that will be accepted when inputting data on a date
>   field. Formats will be tried in order, using the first valid one. Note
>   that these format strings use Python’s datetime module syntax, not the
>   format strings from the date template filter.

and it gives examples.  Using the examples given, in my settings I have placed:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y'             # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
]
```

However, in the [Format Localization documentation (Locale aware input in forms)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms) it says in the note:

> Django uses different formats for displaying data to those it uses for parsing data. Most notably, the formats for parsing dates can’t use the %a (abbreviated weekday name), %A (full weekday name), %b (abbreviated month name), %B (full month name), or %p (AM/PM).

These two sections of the documentation seem to be in conflict and I tend to think that the latter is correct because it is not honoring the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS that I have specified.  How can I validate a date in the form:  August 25, 2017?

Further attempts:
I set USE_L10N to False and set USE_I18N to True and that allows my form to accept dates formatted August 25, 2017, HOWEVER, if I now try to use TIME_INPUT_FORMATS and use the example formats from the documentation (and setting USE_L10N back to True), my form will not validate times in the format: 5:00 PM. Also, setting USE_L10N back to True then causes both the date and the time to not pass forms validation. It just seems like DATE_INPUT_FORMATS and TIME_INPUT_FORMATS don't work as stated in the documentation.

Further attempt:
I imported DATE_INPUT_FORMATS into forms from settings and then placed this in the **init**:
    self.fields['date_due'].input_formats = (DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
With USE_L10N still set to True and USE_I18N False, this now works to validate the date in the format:  August 25, 2017 with the same DATE_INPUT_FORMATS shown above.  HOWEVER, when I then tried the same thing for time (importing TIME_INPUT_FORMATS into forms) and then doing this:

```
self.fields['time_due'].input_formats = (TIME_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

it STILL gives an error when the form validates the time.  Here are the time formats:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%-I:%M %p',    # '2:30 AM/PM'
    '%-I:%M%p'      # '2:30AM/PM'
]
```

To reiterate, it seems like the supposedly global [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) and [TIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#time-input-formats) settings variables are simply being ignored by Django.  I shouldn't have to set these on every form in **init**.

Comment: Your example requires `%B` which is pretty clearly excluded from the parsing, though I agree the first part of the documentation includes`%B` and therefore it should work. However, I don't recommend it, even if you can make it work, because people tend to spell things wrong - e.g., Febuary instead of February, non-native English speakers may enter things incorrectly, etc. The typical solution is to (a) include a popup calendar widget and/or (b) use select fields for Month, Day and Year - with the actual values on Month being numeric even if the display is alpha (e.g., August).

Comment: Thank you.  I actually am using a  [popup calendar widget for Semantic UI](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar), and it auto formats the date as I have stated.  The same thing is happening with TIME_INPUT_FORMATS (the first documentation link says to use the Python datetime module syntax, which includes %p, but then the second documentation link says that %p won't work).  Django typically has excellent documentation, but this is one area that seems fuzzy.